# How can we add a row to an ng-grid and then have that row selected?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

My team have been trying the following:

```
   $scope.addTest = function () {
        var TestRow = {
            "name": "xx",
            "description": "xx",
            "subjectId": 15
        };
        $scope.gridOptions.selectAll()
        var testRowLength = $scope.gridData.push(TestRow);
        $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(testRowLength - 1, true);
    }
```

However the last selectItem does not correctly do a select.  So we tried the following:

```
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.gridData.push(TestRow);
            $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(testRowLength - 1, true);
        });
```

Now we get an error message saying:

```
Error: $apply already in progress
```

This problem is posted as an issue on the ng-grid blog but it's only just been posted and we need help with this as soon as possible. I hope someone can give us advice on how we can

Comment: Hi,in testRowLength you have got the last row added not the length of the grid so may be it will work better with like  var lastRow = $scope.gridData.push(TestRow);
var gridLength = $scope.gridData.length;
$scope.gridOptions.selectItem(gridLength - 1, true);
try with 
var index = this.row.rowIndex;
$scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);

Answer (score 7):

You're selecting the row too soon, use `ngGridEventData` event instead. I push new rows to the beginning of the grid, so scrolling is a little easier:

```
$scope.add = function(){
    var emptyContact = Utilities.newContact();
    var e = $scope.$on('ngGridEventData', function() {
        $scope.contactsGridOptions.selectItem(0, true);
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
        e();
    });

    $scope.contacts.unshift(emptyContact);
};
```

More about scrolling: [How do I scroll an ngGrid to show the current selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487403/how-do-i-scroll-an-nggrid-to-show-the-current-selection)

Related ng-grid issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/354