# How do I force the horizontal scroll move to the right on UI-GRID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scrollbar, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I would like to create a function that would manually position the horizontal scroll bar to the furthest right. I am having a hard time figuring out how to achieve this effect. There was a previous stackoverflow question ([How do I scroll an ngGrid to show the current selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487403/how-do-i-scroll-an-nggrid-to-show-the-current-selection)) similar to mine, but the solution was for NgGrid, an older version of ui-grid. A user posted the solution on getting the ngGrid version to work (http://plnkr.co/edit/oyIlX9?p=preview).

```
$scope.scrollTo = function() {
    var grid = $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid;
    grid.$viewport.scrollTop(grid.rowMap[$scope.index] * grid.config.rowHeight);
};
```

I tried to use the same code for ui-grid, but this newer version doesn't seem to have $viewport. I created a plunker to see an example of what I am working on. The horizontal scroll bar initially starts at the furthest left. I would like to write some code to move it to the furthest right.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SJEoPxelB2HYHLsfZ768?p=preview

If anyone can help me, that would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

With the latest ui-grid, you can scroll to the right of the grid using the scrollTo function on the grid.

```
  $scope.gridApi.grid.scrollTo(data[0],{name:"col8"});
```

First argument is the data row and second argument is the column definition with atleast the name of the column.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KfaJti5BTnyvwjWRhtWe?p=preview is the working version.