# Is there a better way to toggle in and out of edit mode in ng-grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

So far I've only been able to change the edit mode in ng-grid by using separate templates and displaying the correct template based on some user input.

Example: [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUJtlmt6TiysaacdWMZF?p=preview) (re-size a column and then switch to another mode)

This is an issue because any column re-sizing, sorting, or grouping that is preformed is lost when switching from template to template.

Is there a better approach?

### Workaround

If anyone is interested, I created a workaround for myself by modify ng-grid.js 2.0.7

First I modified the cellEditTemplate.html and added the attribute disable-Cell=\"!isEditing\" (isEditing is a scope variable from the controller which would be required with this workaround)

```
    $templateCache.put("cellEditTemplate.html",
      "<div ng-cell-has-focus disable-Cell=\"!isEditing\" ng-dblclick=\"editCell()\">\n" +
      "\t<div ng-edit-cell-if=\"!isFocused\">\t\n" +
      "\t\tDISPLAY_CELL_TEMPLATE\n" +
      "\t</div>\n" +
      "\t<div ng-edit-cell-if=\"isFocused\">\n" +
      "\t\tEDITABLE_CELL_TEMPLATE\n" +
      "\t</div>\n" +
      "</div>"
    );
```

Then I modified the ngCellHasFocus directive and added a $watch on the disableCell attribute. When disableCell is set to true I prevent the click and mousedown event from firing in that directive.

```
            return function ($scope, elm, attrs) {
                var disabled = false;
                //Added $watch
                $scope.$watch(attrs.disableCell, function (newVal) {
                    disabled = newVal;
                });
                var isFocused = false;
                var isCellEditableOnMouseDown = false;

                $scope.editCell = function () {
                    if (!$scope.enableCellEditOnFocus) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            focusOnInputElement($scope, elm);
                        }, 0);
                    }
                };
                elm.bind('mousedown', function (evt) {
                    //Added return
                    if (disabled) return;
                    if ($scope.enableCellEditOnFocus) {
                        isCellEditableOnMouseDown = true;
                    } else {
                        elm.focus();
                    }
                    return true;
                });
                elm.bind('click', function (evt) {
                    //Added return
                    if (disabled) return;
                    if ($scope.enableCellEditOnFocus) {
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        isCellEditableOnMouseDown = false;
                        focusOnInputElement($scope, elm);
                    }
                });
                elm.bind('focus', function (evt) {
                    isFocused = true;
                    if ($scope.enableCellEditOnFocus && !isCellEditableOnMouseDown) {
                        focusOnInputElement($scope, elm);
                    }
                    return true;
                });
                elm.bind('blur', function () {
                    isFocused = false;
                    return true;
                });
                elm.bind('keydown', function (evt) {
                    if (!$scope.enableCellEditOnFocus) {
                        if (isFocused && evt.keyCode !== 37 && evt.keyCode !== 38 && evt.keyCode !== 39 && evt.keyCode !== 40 &&    evt.keyCode !== 9 && !evt.shiftKey && evt.keyCode !== 13) {
                            focusOnInputElement($scope, elm);
                        }
                        if (isFocused && evt.shiftKey && (evt.keyCode >= 65 && evt.keyCode <= 90)) {
                            focusOnInputElement($scope, elm);
                        }
                        if (evt.keyCode === 27) {
                            elm.focus();
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                });
            };
        }]);
```

And here are my grid options

```
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'myData',
            enableColumnResize: true,
            enableCellSelection: true,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
            columnDefs: 'columnDefs',
            plugins: [layoutPlugin],
            //My row template has a ng-dblClick() attached to it for navigation in non-edit mode
            rowTemplate: 'Templates/gridRowView.html'
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I researched this a bit and from what I can tell there isn't any way to change a number of the grid configuration settings dynamically (including the edit behavior). In fact, [issue #128](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/128) in the ng-grid git repository makes me think this feature isn't planned in the future either. You can still [change the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405785/how-to-dynamically-configure-ng-grid) or [update the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143566/how-can-we-add-a-row-to-an-ng-grid-and-then-have-that-row-selected) dynamically but I don't think that will help you at all. With that in mind, the approach you took, or an if/switch will work well.

The other alternative is to use a different edit mode such as the "Excel-like" edit mode. If you search [the examples page](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) for this there is an excellent example. This might be a healthy compromise between no-editing and editing without actually requiring any changes to the configuration to switch between the modes. I hope this helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any simple decision, and have solved problem this way:
You can assign a string to columnDefs option of your grid.
After this assignment you can change columnDefs and grid can see this changes.
In columns you can change enableCellEdit.

```
$scope.columnDefs = [{ field:"name", displayName: "NAME", enableCellEdit: true},
                     { field:"age", displayName: "AGE", enableCellEdit: true}];


var options = { data: 'myData',
                columnDefs: 'columnDefs',
                multiSelect: false,
                enableCellEditOnFocus: true};


$scope.gridOptions = options;

$scope.makeReadOnly = function() {
    for(i in $scope.columnDefs)
      $scope.columnDefs[i].enableCellEdit = false;
}
```

Code in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3Xoao5?p=info

I found decision after reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405872/488848